# Javascript: Finding the most middle value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Okay, so what I need to do is return the most middle value in an array. And I'm supposed to use `Math.round` to calculate the middle index in the array. Just to be clear, I'm NOT talking about the **median**, just the middle value.

That's what I need to do in text, since I'm new at javascript I don't however know how to quite execute this. Any ideas?

Also, if you think,this question doesn't belong here or is stupid, please direct me to somewhere where I can find this information, I'm just trying to learn here.

```
function test(arr) {


}
```

Comment: given `[11,22,33,44]`, what should it return?

Comment: The amount of numbers are uneven so there is always one that's the middle one

Comment: @AndrewP you should have included the info that the amount of numbers is always uneven in the question, it affects the answer a lot.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you have an array with for example five items, the middle item is at index two:

```
var arr = [ item, item, middle, item, item];
```

Dividing the length by two and using `Math.round` would give you index three rather than two, so you would need to subtract one from the length first:

```
var middle = arr[Math.round((arr.length - 1) / 2)];
```

You say in your question that you are supposed to use `Math.round`, but if that is not a requirement, you can get the same result easier using `Math.floor`:

```
var middle = arr[Math.floor(arr.length / 2)];
```

For an array with an even number of items, that will give you the second of the two items that are in the middle. If you want the first instead, use `Math.floor` and substract one from the length. That still gives the same result for odd number of items:

```
var middle = arr[Math.floor((arr.length - 1) / 2)];
```

Comment: This definitly seems like the way to go, i cannot get it to work for some reason though. Am I correct to put the second string of code in your comment into the {} from my original post and then return middle; after it? Would this return the middle value?

Comment: @AndrewP: Yes, that's how to use it. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/xuxaL/

Answer (score 25):

Get the middle index of the array:

```js
const arr = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0];
const theMiddle = Math.floor(arr.length / 2); // index 2
const value = arr[theMiddle]; // value 1
```

One-liner:

```js
const value = arr[arr.length / 2 | 0];
```

Comment: May want to `floor()` instead. If `array.length` is `1`, `Math.ceil(1/2)` is also `1` and out-of-bounds.

Comment: So if the array were 5, 3, 8 theMiddle would be 3? because that's what i'm after

Comment: Yes. It is based on the index, not the value.

Comment: Vote for one-liner

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one too:

```
function test(arr){      
  var middle_index = parseInt((arr.length/2).toFixed(), 10) - 1;
  if(middle_index === -1)
    alert('Array empty');
  else
    alert('Middle value in array ['+arr+'] is '+arr[middle_index]);
}
```

**[DEMO Link](http://jsbin.com/esutIGEV/2)**