# How to select the middle of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I thought I could use

```
$ [1,2,3,4,5].splice((this.length / 2), 1)[0]
```

but it gives me

```
$ 1
```

I tried

```
$ [1,2,3,4,5].splice(function() { return this[this.length / 2, 1]})
```

but it gives me

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

I'm looking for a solution that gives me an integer and for even arrays is the lower of the two, e.g.

```
[1,2,3,4] givees 2
[1,2,3,4,5] gives 3
[1,2,3,4,5,6] gives 3
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] gives 4
```

Comment: please add the wanted result

Comment: `splice` doesn’t accept functions. `splice` _mutates_ the array and returns an array containing the deleted elements. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). What is the `$` at the beginning of your code blocks?

Comment: What do you want exactly as output? An array? Could you clarify your question? I though you wanted the middle element?

Comment: What if the array has an even number of elements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [finding Middle element of an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36254254/finding-middle-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/20904368/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50425313/3001761 - please do research before asking (and if you have done it, please show it in the question).

Comment: Thanks as always Jon.  I hoped to accept the others answer to mark mine as dupe but when I tried it out I had issues using it.  Also my requirements were unclear so I updated them.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant my answer works on the test cases you provided.

Comment: *"when I tried it out I had issues using it"* - then give a [mre]. As an experienced user you should be doing as [ask] suggests by default.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `this` reference. Try this:

```js
console.log(getMiddle([1,2,3,4]));
console.log(getMiddle([1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(getMiddle([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
console.log(getMiddle([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]));

function getMiddle(arr){
     return arr.splice(Math.floor((arr.length-1) / 2), 1)[0]
}
```

However, As @jonrsharpe 's comment states, splicing a single-element array from an index to the same index plus one then getting the first value in the result creates a redundant array. A better way to get the middle element would be the following:

```js
console.log(getMiddle([1,2,3,4]));
console.log(getMiddle([1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(getMiddle([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
console.log(getMiddle([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]));

function getMiddle(arr){
     return arr[Math.floor((arr.length - 1) / 2)];
}
```

Comment: I would delete the first suggestion entirely - splicing a single-element array from an index to the same index plus one then getting the first value in the result creates a redundant array, the second is much neater.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes the second one is neater, but the first is just to solve the OP problem in the used method. I added some explanations tho. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `this` as a parameter because [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is supposed to be called inside functions, whereas splice accept as parameters integers. If you really want to use `this` you may use a prototype. Use [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) function since arrays indexes only accept integers, and `Math.floor` rounds up to the lowest integer (ex: `Math.floor(2.5) === 2`).

```js
Array.prototype.getMiddle = function () {
  return this[Math.floor(this.length/2)]
}

console.log([1,2,3,4,5].getMiddle()) // 3
```

The above function only works when the length of the array is an odd number, since arrays whose length is an even number do not have "middle" element.

If you want to check if the array has a middle

```js
Array.prototype.getMiddle = function () {
  return (this.length % 2) ? this[Math.floor(this.length/2)] : null
}

console.log([1,2,3,4,5].getMiddle()) // 3
console.log([1,2,4,5].getMiddle()) // null
```

Alternative solutions:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

var middleEl = arr[Math.floor(arr.length/2)] 

console.log(middleEl) // 3
```

If you want to use `splice`

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

var middleEl = arr.splice((arr.length / 2), 1)[0]

console.log(middleEl)
```

If you want a function

```js
console.log(middleEl([1,2,3,4,5])) //3
console.log(middleEl([1,2,4,5])) //null

function middleEl (arr) {
   return (arr.length % 2) ? arr[Math.floor(arr.length/2)] : null
}
```

Comment: @user4642212 ok, ok, the result is the same, but you're right, parseInt is made for converting strings to integers, but they also round up number.

Comment: @user4642212 the questions says `How to select the middle of an array?`. What am I reading wrong? Am I supposed to be an expert in hermeneutics?

Comment: @user4642212 whatever, I give you now four different ways of calculating, explaining why you can't use `this` with splice, since splice only accepts integers as parameters, even presenting a prototype wherein you can use `this`. I hope now it suffices.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like that.

```
var data, remaining, hold, result;
data = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8", "9"];
remaining = data.length % 2;
hold = Math.floor(data.length / 2);
result = data[(remaining + hold - 1)];
document.write(result);
```

Comment: But of course you should check;
if(remaining == 0)
document.write("This array length is double");

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
let len = arr.length;
let mid = Math.floor(len / 2);
console.log(arr[mid]);
// or
console.log(arr.slice(mid, mid + 1));
```

or if you want the middle two, you can do mid + 2 using a var that tests to see if the length is even.

Comment: or if you want the middle two, you can do `mid + 2` using a var that tests to see if the length is even.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a prototype for getting the middle element/s.

```js
Array.prototype.middle = function () {
    const
        half = this.length >> 1,
        offset = 1 - this.length % 2;
    
    return this.slice(half - offset, half + 1);
};

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].middle());    // [3]
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].middle()); // [3, 4]
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].middle());       // [2, 3]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply, assuming `a.length > 0`:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(a[(a.length - 1) >> 1])
const b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
console.log(b[(b.length - 1) >> 1])
```

I think this should be a fairly fast way of doing it.  The `>>` operator is an integer shift, which divides the number by two - ignoring decimals.